# Drop-in replacement for enumerate that ranks the elements being passed so that ties don't increase rank?

Tags: python, algorithm, ranking

I've been hoping someone would ask this specific question on Stackoverflow, but since no-one has yet: How do I make an iterator like enumerate that ranks the scores so that ties don't increase the rank number?

For example, I want to give the rank for a sorted list of scores and names in the form, `score`, `name`.

```
scores = [(42, 'Adams'), (42, 'Douglas'), (41, 'Aaron'), 
          (41, 'Hall'), (39, 'Python')]
```

I could use enumerate to get the place for each name,

```
for i, (s, name) in enumerate(scores, 1):
    print i, s, name
```

But each line would decrease ranking even if two or more were tied for the same score. This is [ordinal ranking as described in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Ordinal_ranking_.28.221234.22_ranking.29).

```
1 42 Adams
2 42 Douglas
3 41 Aaron
4 41 Hall
5 39 Python
```

**How do I accomplish this without incrementing if they're tied for score, knowing that I need the same API for the function so that it's a drop-in replacement for enumerate?** This is described as [standard competition ranking in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_.28.221224.22_ranking.29).

Here's the [`enumerate` equivalency written in Python from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this specific problem when I first started where I'm currently working and was trucking through the training material, but I was frustrated as I climbed the rankings that I was given a lower ranking than others I was tied with. This was my first contribution to the code base, but tightened up a bit (because, embarrassingly, I didn't use `enumerate` the first time around!)

My solution, is to use a generator I originally modeled on the [enumerate equivalency code in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) (see question above).

```
def rank(sequence, start=0): #as in enumerate()
    '''
    rank generator function handles score ties, 
    same API as enumerate for drop-in replacement
    assumes given a sorted sequence of two-tuples 
    of scores and names (or some other description)
    '''
    rank = start
    previous_score = None # need to initialize 
    for n, (score, name) in enumerate(sequence, start): 
        if score != previous_score: #rank up if not tie
            rank = n
        previous_score = score
        yield rank, (score, name) #rank unmodified if a tie.
```

And usage:

```
for i, (s, name) in rank(scores, 1):
    print i, s, name
```

would print:

```
1 42 Adams
1 42 Douglas
3 41 Aaron
3 41 Hall
5 39 Python
```

Comment: I would've gone for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group equally-scored items. A `key` argument for how to compute scores might be a useful addition (or it might just be cruft if you never need it).

Comment: @user2357112 I'm intrigued, how would you do that?

Comment: Nothing particularly interesting. I tried it, and it didn't end up any cleaner than yours, since you want the rankings to advance by the size of the group rather than 1 when you finish a group.

Comment: @user2357112 I tried it too when you suggested it, but it didn't come out well.

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia entry it seems like standard competition ranking is most likely to start from 1, hence the change to the default start value.

This routine *automatically handles initialization without an arbitrary value* and relies on item[0] of each item in the iterable being comparable.

```
>>> def sc_rank(iterable, start=1):
    """Standard competition ranking"""
    first = True
    for n, item in enumerate(iterable, start):
        if first:
            first = False
            lastresult, lastrank = item[0], n
            yield start, item
        else:
            if item[0] == lastresult:
                yield lastrank, item
            else:
                yield n, item
                lastresult, lastrank = item[0], n


>>> for scr, item in sc_rank(scores):
    print(scr, item)


1 (42, 'Adams')
1 (42, 'Douglas')
3 (41, 'Aaron')
3 (41, 'Hall')
5 (39, 'Python')
>>>
```

Comment: That actually seems a bit more convoluted. I don't see the advantages.

Comment: Neither do I now I have it down.